# Cannot get/view list of a single user (me) likes using Facebook API

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Does anyone have a sample of code to show how to access a user's likes.  I have successfully let the user login and can see much of their info (name, email, ...) by simple using the response. method (i.e. response.email).  But I am also trying to see the array of that user's likes.  It seems that is needs to be addressed in a different array style, but I cannot find or figure out the way to access them.

I am pretty sure I have the permission scope correct and I am able to verify that likes are returned without error.  Here is the function where I would like to show the likes.  I get to my Here alert box so I pretty confident that I am getting back without errors.

I just cannot figure out the proper way to address the returned values in the response object for likes.  How do you see the values?  I would assume a loop with some sort of method to specify a single value.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getLikes() 
{
    FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) 
    {
        if(response.data) 
        {
            alert("Here");
        } 
        else     
        {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my first post and I hope that I have provided enough information to make my question clear.

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(response.data)` and looked at the response object?

Comment: Good idea.  I added it after my alert("Here"); statement and I get [] (an empty return set).  This seems to be another issue as I set up my test user to have several likes.  I still would not know how to access the data if the object was not empty though.  Thanks for the suggestion.  At least I can be chasing that issue down also.

Comment: I went back to my test user and my likes were missing.  I have added them and now the console.log show my array.  I can play with this to see if I can access the data, but if anyone knows how it is done, that would be great..  Thanks again.

Comment: With the ability to see the likes with the console.log (and making sure they exist), I was able to access the data.  The format for the data points are read like this:  response.data.length - gives the number of likes and response.data[1].name, response.data[1].id, and response.data[1].created_time yield the actual data.  Easy peasy once you actually have data.  Thanks again for getting me started down the road.